# Problems running gradlew.bat and setting up Development Environment

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've recently gotten into modding Minecraft 1.7.10, and I'm setting up my folders/environment. All I've done so far is as follows;

1. Extracted the 1.7.10 src files from the forge website to the file I plan on modding in.
2. made a system variable in my environmental variables called Path, which directs to my JDK.
3. Ran gradlew.bat (failed)

And this is where I failed. I have the main error I got straight from the cmd prompt, used cmd /k switch to keep it open listed below.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Modding Project'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:jobs:3.5.300-v20130429-1813
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:3.5.100-v20130422-1538
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:expressions:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:expressions.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:filesystem:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:filesystem.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse:osgi:[3.7.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse:osgi.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.6.100,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:jobs:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:jobs.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:contenttype:[3.3.0,4.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:contenttype.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:app:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
> Required by:
> :Modding Project:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
> > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:app.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.107 secs

I can provide the --stacktrace, --info or the --debug on request.. first post so I'm not sure what people need beyond the error. Thanks anyways!

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"
      
    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Now here is my NEW build.gradle thanks to your help, narrowing it down now.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Modding Project'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download artifact 'com.github.jponge:lzma-java:1.3:lzma-java.jar'
> > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jponge/lzma-java/1.3/lzma-java-1.3.jar'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.195 secs

Comment: As far as I remember you need to run `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` first. Did you run it?

Comment: I did initially yeah, it gives the same output as when I run the gradlew.bat file

Comment: Ok guess I've faced this problem before. Please provide your `build.gradle` file just for me to be sure.

Comment: Done, added my build.gradle

Comment: So do I understand you correctly: instead of many unresolved dependencies now you have only one unresolved dependency but with the same error?

Comment: I did yes, but I've figured it out thanks to your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I understood `repo1.maven.org/maven2` does not support http anymore. That is problem because 1.7.10 is shipped with gradle wrapper v2.0. In this version http was hardcoded. So you need to add repository by yourself.

Repository declaration looks like:

```
maven {
  name = "maven"
  url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
}
```

You need to add it to the buildscript and to the project.

It probably will look like that:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           name = "maven"
           url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "maven"
        url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"
      
    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Also you can upgrade your gradle version. But I prefer not to do it because ForgeGradle is not very stable.

Also you can use [it](https://gitlab.com/hvalick2111/cutter/-/blob/master/forge/1.7.10/build.gradle) as reference in case of further issues.

Comment: Alright!  it's narrowed down my errors, now only one thing left. I have updated my build.gradle with the https and the maven2, this is my output when I enter gradlew setupDecompWorkspace as of now

`
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Modding Project'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'com.github.jponge:lzma-java:1.3:lzma-java.jar'
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jponge/lzma-java/1.3/lzma-java-1.3.jar'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
`

Comment: Actually scratch the comment above, I'll add the code to my original post. it doesn't work so well in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Forge doesn't use maven.org as main storage for ForgeGradle.
I've used this patch in build.gradle file to do the work for 1.7.10-1614:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

No others changes to the rest of files.

Answer (score 0):

so what did you changed in your build.gradlew that this stoped to appear and gradlew setupDecompWorkspace worked?

```
C:\Users\....\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src>gradlew setupDecompWorkspace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'com.github.jponge:lzma-java:1.3:lzma-java.jar'
      > Could not HEAD 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/com/github/jponge/lzma-java/1.3/lzma-java-1.3.jar'. Received status code 308 from server: Permanent Redirect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.86 secs

C:\Users\....\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src>
```